# Geometry problem on circles from a competition

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

Triangle $\triangle ABC$ is an equilateral triangle whose side is $16$. A circle meets the sides of the triangle at $6$ points:

- it intersects $AC$ at $G$ and $F$ and $|AG|=2$, $|GF|=13$, $|FC|=1$.
- it intersects $AB$ at $H$ and $J$ and $|AH|=3$, $|HJ|=7$, $|JB|=6$.
- it intersects $BC$ at $D$ and $E$.

Find $|DE|$ using plane geometry concepts.

Comment: Six points??! ${}{}$

Comment: @Babak: I assume the circle need not meet the triangle at the vertices...

Comment: the circe does not meet the vertices of the triangle but only intersects the sides at six points

Comment: give a solution based on plane geometry

Comment: @sangabattulalokesh: and by that you mean...?

Comment: @sangabattulalokesh [Here](https://brilliant.org/i/vQiTjW/) is a similar problem for you to work on, taken from the current set of problems on Brilliant.org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ["Power of a Point" (with respect to a circle) Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) ---in particular, its incarnation as the Secant-Secant Power Theorem--- comes in handy here. Relative to the six-point circle of this problem, the theorem states that 
$$\begin{align}
|AH|\cdot|AJ| &= |AG|\cdot|AF| &(=\text{power of }A) \\
|BD|\cdot|BE| &= |BJ|\cdot|BH| &(=\text{power of }B) \\
|CF|\cdot|CG| &= |CE|\cdot|CD| &(=\text{power of }C)
\end{align}$$

Substituting in known values ...
$$\begin{align}
3\cdot(3+7) &= 2\cdot(2+13) &= 30\\
|BD|\cdot|BE| &= 6\cdot(6+7)&= 78\\
1\cdot(1+13) &= |CE|\cdot|CD| &= 14
\end{align}$$
(The first equation isn't relevant to the problem at hand, but it's a nice check.)

Therefore, assuming the point ordering $B, D, E, C$, we have
$$\begin{align}
78 &= |BD|\cdot\left(|BC|-|CE|\right) = |BD|\cdot\left(16-|CE|\right)  \\
14 &= |CE|\cdot\left(|BC|-|BD|\right) = |CE|\cdot\left(16-|BD|\right)
\end{align}$$
Subtracting the second equation from the first gives
$$64 = 16 \left( |BD|- |CE| \right) \qquad \implies \qquad |CE| = |BD| - 4$$
Thus,
$$\begin{align}
78 = |BD|\cdot \left( 20 - |BD| \right) \qquad &\implies \qquad |BD| = 10 \pm \sqrt{22} \\
&\implies \qquad |CE| = \phantom{1}6 \pm \sqrt{22}
\end{align}$$
so that
$$\begin{align}
|BD|+|DE|+|EC|=|BC| = 16 \qquad &\implies \qquad |DE| = 16 - \left( 16 \pm 2\sqrt{22} \right) \\
&\implies \qquad |DE| = 2\sqrt{22}
\end{align}$$
(since we presumably want a non-negative $|DE|$).

---

I like that this solution begins with one of my favorite geometric theorems, but the ensuing algebra seems un-inspiringly mechanical. I suspect that there's a solution maintaining a more-geometric spirit throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the triangle is drawn with $A$ as the topmost point, $B$ as the left base point and $C$ as the right base point.

The equation for the circle is $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$, where $(x_0, y_0)$ is the centre coordinates and $r$ is the radius. Assume a coordinate system with the origin at $B$. Now the coordinates for the points $G$, $H$ and $J$ are found to be $(9,7 \sqrt{3})$, $(13/2, 13 \sqrt{3}/2)$ and $(3, 7 \sqrt{3})$ respectively. Putting these numbers in the equation for the circle gives you the following equation system:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
  (7 \sqrt{3} - y_0)^2 + (9 - x_0)^2 = r^2 \\
  (13 \sqrt{3} / 2 - y_0)^2 + (13/2 - x_0)^2 = r^2 \\
  (3 \sqrt{3} - y_0)^2 + (3 - x_0)^2 = r^2
\end{array}\right.$$

The solution (with positive $r$) is $x_0 = 10$, $y_0 = 3 \sqrt{3}$ and $r=7$.

Note that circle is completely defined by three points only. By plugging in the coordinates of the point $F$ into the circle equation one can verify that the above solution is correct (assuming the problem makers have done their job).

Now, $|DE|$ is simply the difference between the two solutions of the resulting circle equation when $y=0$, i.e.

$$|DE| = 2 \sqrt{r^2-y_0^2} = 2 \sqrt{22}$$

Comment: i mean the answer what you gave is also correct but i needed a plane geometrical approach

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions are fine if the question is asking for $|DE|$ only.

However, this is not the end of the story because ....

After  $|DE| = 2 \sqrt{22}$ has been found, we still need to find

(1) the correct value of $|BD|$ (which was found to be $10 \pm \sqrt{22}$)

---After testing,

----$|BD|$ shoud be $10 - \sqrt{22}$ only. [Not just simply take it for granted to accept the positive root.]

(2) the correct value of $|CE|$ (which was found to be $6 \pm \sqrt{22}$)

----$|CE|$ shoud be $6 - \sqrt{22}$ only.